# Having dynamic height of a view inside a row in Listview

Tags: listview, android

I want to build somthing like this, where each row is divided in to two halves and each one of them might have different height based on the content. Right now I am using listview and can't achieve this. Any leads on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for Staggered `GridView`. A quick search on Google shows 2 open source libraries:

1. https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid
   [image]
2. https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView
   [image]

Comment: I recommend Etsy's `StaggeredGridView` as well. I have been using it for a long time and works perfectly.